# Excel VBA - Userform checkbox duplicating row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a checkbox that needs to return a value of "1" or "-1" to the worksheet instead of "TRUE" or "FALSE". (My spreadsheet converts 1 to Yes and -1 to No)

The code sort of works, but its using true/false on the row with my data, and using the 1 / -1 on the very next line (see screenshot). The grey lines in the screenshot are the duplicate rows. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code for the checkbox:

```
If ConstRel.Value Then
ws.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 10).Value = "1"
Else
ws.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 10).Value = "-1"
End If
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc8Gu.jpg)

Comment: FALSE (aka No) is zero and anything that is not FALSE is TRUE. While a worksheet's TRUE is numerically 1, VBA's True is numerically -1. Why would you opt to change that?

Comment: You should check which row is selected when you do the `.End(xlUp)`, but before the offset (since the offset is moving one row down and 10 columns to the right).

Comment: Jeeped- I already have the spreadsheet setup that way. The conditional formatting / cell format uses 1 for “Yes” (TRUE) and -1 for “NO” (FALSE”). I can see if I can change it easily, but it’s in multiple places.

Comment: Mistella- how would I go about this? The userform adds a row to the end of the populated rows each time the save button is pressed in the form. Thanks for the assistance to both of you! I’m pretty good in Excel, but totally new to VBA.